# Rails 5 route calling wrong controller on logout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a user authentication system that works for login, forgot password and change profile info, but my logout route is going wacky on me and gives me the error `The action 'destroy' could not be found for PagesController`.  I don't know why its calling the PagesController.  I have a namespaced PagesController for admin actions and a pages controller just for the `show` method.  Like I said, everything works perfectly except for the session logout.  Thank you.

**routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'password_resets/new'
  get 'password_resets/edit'
  get 'sessions/new'
  get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  get 'contact-me', to: 'messages#new', as: 'new_message'
  post 'contact-me', to: 'messages#create', as: 'create_message'
  resources :articles
  mount ImageUploader.upload_endpoint(:cache) => '/images/upload'
  mount StripeEvent::Engine, at: '/webhooks/stripe'

  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
    resources :pages
    resources :articles
    resources :categories
    resources :tags
    resources :albums
    resources :banners
    resources :products do
      resources :variations
    end
  end

  resources :products do
    resources :variations
  end

  root 'pages#show', defaults: { id: 'home' } # shows home page as default from pages controller
  resources :pages, path: ''
end
```

**logout link**

```
<%= button_to 'Logout', logout_path, method: :delete %>
```

**sessions_controller**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      if user.activated?
        log_in user
        params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
        redirect_back_or user
      else
        message  = "Account not activated. "
        message += "Check your email for the activation link."
        flash[:warning] = message
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    log_out if logged_in?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```

**sessions_helper**

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remembers a user in a persistent session.
  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end

  # Returns true if the given user is the current user.
  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(:remember, cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  # Forgets a persistent session.
  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  # Logs out the current user.
  def log_out
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  # Redirects to stored location (or to the default).
  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:forwarding_url] || default)
    session.delete(:forwarding_url)
  end

  # Stores the URL trying to be accessed.
  def store_location
    session[:forwarding_url] = request.original_url if request.get?
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```

and recheck your routes with

```
rake routes | grep logout
```

hope it's help

Comment: brilliant!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `method` `get` to `delete`

```
delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
```